# Reack.JS Form Multiple Input with useState

Tags: reactjs, react-native

It is already 2 days i am trying to figure out how to save value for all form input fields.I am passing props to child and can not update useState

My parent component

````
             <CustomInput
              classes={`col-12 ${classes.p15} ${classes.item} ${props.classes}`}
              controlId="FormInputPhoneNumber"
              dark={props.dark == true ? true : null}
              placeholder="Phone Number"
              name="phone"
              simple={false}
              leftIconn={true}
              icon={<Phone />}
              type="text"
            />
    ```
````

And my child component: Through props i`m passing name, want to update value and then pass those value back to parent component

```
    const CustomInput = (props) => {
  console.log(props);

  const handleInputChange = (e) => {
    console.log("this is inputs", inputs);
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    setInput({ ...inputs, [name]: value });
  };
  const [inputs, setInput] = useState({
    email: "",
    fullName: "",
    phone: "",
    message: "",
  });

  const type = props.type || "text";
  const simple = props.simple + "" || "false";
  return (
    <Form.Group
      className={`CustomInput ${props.classes} ${props.size} ${
        props.dark ? `dark` : ""
      }`}
      controlId={props.controlId}
    >
      {props.label ? <Form.Label>{props.label}</Form.Label> : null}
    {!props.contactUsModal ? (
        //Form to Let`s get started
        <InputGroup className="leftIcon">
          <InputGroup.Prepend>
            <InputGroup.Text>{props.icon}</InputGroup.Text>
          </InputGroup.Prepend>
          <Form.Control
            type={type}
            placeholder={props.placeholder}
            name={props.name}
            required={true}
            value={
              props.name === "email"
                ? inputs.name
                : null || props.fullName === "fullName"
                ? inputs.fullName
                : null || props.name == "message"
                ? inputs.message
                : null || props.name === "phone"
                ? inputs.phone
                : null
            }
            onChange={handleInputChange()}
          />
        </InputGroup>
      ) : null}
    </Form.Group>
  );
};

export default CustomInput;
```

In console.log i see that it does not save input value.

[image]

Comment: **A tip:** don't use `onChange={handleInputChange()}`. either use `onChange={handleInputChange}` or use `onChange={() => handleInputChange()}`.

Comment: I fixed it, but still state is not updating properly

Comment: I think you're not updating your state in the `onChange` handler. You can use the `name` attibute/prop to handle the updating. Please have a look in the following [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/unruffled-rain-i843p?file=/src/App.js).